# enable CORS in docker for rails apps rest-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cross-domain, ruby-on-rails-5, rest-client

I have two applications running in separate docker images. First is exposed on ports 3000:3000 and second 4000:4000. First application has some resources which I wanna get by second application using rest-client.

Probably it's a problem with docker containers.

Here are errors:

- **Errno::ECONNREFUSED in FilmsController#index**
- **Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000)**

//FIRST APPLICATION:

- exposes resources on **http://localhost:3000/movies**
- is open for other networks
- allows cross origin request

application.rb file for first application

```
module Movies
   class Application < Rails::Application
      config.web_console.whiny_requests = false

      config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
        allow do
          origins '*'
          resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, 
          :options]
       end
     end
  end
end
```

//SECOND APPLICATION:

- runs on port:4000
- has one model Film
- one controller

Film model:

```
class Film
  require 'rest-client'
    def self.all
      RestClient.get 'localhost:3000/movies.json'
  end
end
```

films_controller:

```
class FilmsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Film.all
  end
end
```

Everything was working fine since it was one application. The problem appears when I split into **two docker containers**. I guess that **one container blocks request from another**, but couldn't find solution. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each docker container runs in a separate networking namespace by default, which includes getting its own private loopback interface (aka localhost) that is separate from every other container and the host. To connect between two containers, they need to be on the same docker network, and then as long as that network is not the default network named "bridge" (the name, not the network driver), you can connect between containers using their container name. Note that you do not need to publish or expose the port for container to container networking, that former is only needed for allowing external access to the container.

So if you are using `docker run` (otherwise you should include your docker-compose.yml), you would have:

```
docker network create railsnet
docker run --net railsnet --name=app1 ...
docker run --net railsnet --name=app2 ...
```

And then if app1 listened on port 3000 inside the container, you could connect from app2 to app1:3000/xyz.

Comment: Thank you for your answear. I've started the containers and then attached them to the network by typipng:  `docker network create railsnet` `docker network connect railsnet app1` `docker network connect railsnet app2` BUT THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION

Comment: Please explain why this is not a solution for you, and if you experienced a new error.

Comment: The error is still the same. I am sure that this problem is a 'docker problem', because when I test the applications on the other computer (without docker) everything works fine.

Comment: If the error is the same, then you did not follow the above steps with the environment you're testing against. Please update your question with the steps you did follow.

Comment: I use docker-compose.yml for both application. What exactly should I add to docker-compose to implement your suggestions?

Comment: For advice on what to change in your docker-compose.yml, please include that file in your question. If your output still shows connections to localhost, then you've only run the 3 code lines above without following the rest of the advice.

Comment: This is how it looks like. I am sorry that it's not viewing properly. Pinging between conatiners works, but Rails apps don't. I know that it might look like Rails problem, but it's not, becouse on the other machine without docker apps are working

Comment: This is the comments section of an answer, your question is above and includes an edit link. Please use that space to post updates to your question. Posting code like this in comments is not readable. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Finaly I found the solution. I've setup the docker-compose.yml properly :) Unfortunatelly I can't put it properly in the comment body. Thank you BMitch!